# Load Multi-dimensional numpy array from binary string

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to load a multi-dimensional numpy array from binary string.

```py
multi_dim_arr = convert_bin_to_npy(binary_string)
```

It is established that the `binary_string` above is a multi-dimensional numpy array. To check if function works properly, I can verify it by the following method:

```py
with open('data.npy', 'rb') as f:
         binary_string = f.read()

multi_dim_arr = convert_bin_to_npy(binary_string)
```

I am aware of `np.fromstring()` method, however, the array loses its dimensionality. I am looking for a possible method through which I can obtain all information of the numpy Array through its binary string and then reconstruct the array.

I am using Python 3.6

Comment: np.load() function should do exactly what you wanted to do

Answer (score 0):

you can use `np.load` function to load array saved using `np.save` and it will preserve the shape as well

Here is example code

```py
arr = np.arange(200).reshape(20,10)
print(arr.shape)
np.save('arr.npy', arr)

arr2 = np.load('arr.npy')
print(arr2.shape)
```

Comment: Hi. I am aware of the `np.load()` function however for my use case, I am not reading a file. I specifically want to parse the binary string to get multi-dimensional array. I will clarify this in the question.